# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '’' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I'm trying to awnswer this question:
When did the customer with customer_ID ''NN8'', travel to Wien, and for how much ?

These are my tables

''Ticket'' table (with foreignkeys Customer_ID and Ticket_ID)
`Attributes are:
[Customer_ID][Ticket_ID]`
  `NN8        ETG987`

''Destination'' table (with Primary key ticket_ID)
Attributes are:
`[Ticket_ID][city][Price][Country][departure_date][departure_time][arrival_date][arrival_time][departure_city][arrival_city]`

(Values in linear order are) 
`[ETG987][Wien][Austria][20151212][17:00][20151212][20:00][Karlstad][Wien]`

This is the command I'm typing in:

```
Select ticket.customer_ID, destination.departure_time, destination.arrival_city, destination.price 
FROM ticket, destination
Where ticket.ticket_ID=destination.ticket_ID and arrival_city=’%Wien%’
```

Then I'm getting this error message:

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '’' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 2):

In `’%Wien%’`, you have to use a proper single quote (`'`) instead of this weird quote `’`.

Don't use Microsoft Word for writing SQL code.

Comment: And you probably want to either remove the percent signs for an `=` i.e. `arrival_city = 'Wien'` or use `arrival_city LIKE '%Wien%'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select 
  ticket.customer_ID, destination.departure_time, 
  destination.arrival_city, destination.price 
FROM ticket t
INNER JOIN destination d ON ticket.ticket_ID=destination.ticket_ID 
WHERE arrival_city LIKE '%Wien%'
```

In the above query I have changed your quotation style around `%Wien%` and implemented `JOIN`s

Comment: When I wrote this, I got empty columns, how come?

Comment: Oops my bad. Instead of `= '%Wien%'` I should have written `LIKE '%Wien%'`. That has been corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HAVING instead of WHERE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).